# How to integrate recoil library with react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, recoiljs

I'm trying the new state management library from facebook [recoil](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil), I tried the [Getting started](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started) example on a reactjs project and it worked perfectly. After that I tried recoil on a react-native project but I got an error:

[image: Error message]

Here's the code I've tried:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {RecoilRoot} from 'recoil';
import RecoilTest from './RecoilTest';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <RecoilTest />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
};

export default App;
```

RecoilTest.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useRecoilState} from 'recoil';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {textState} from './Atoms';

const RecoilTest = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useRecoilState(textState);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RecoilTest;
```

Atoms.js

```
import {atom} from 'recoil';

export const textState = atom({
  key: 'textState',
  default: 'initial value',
});
```

Comment: For such a young library you should post an issue on their github.

Answer (score 3):

Recoil don't has a fully support to react native yet

Comment: do they have full support now Feb 2022?

Answer (score 3):

It is supported in nightly build. If you want to try before it is released with next version, you can install it doing:

```
yarn add https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil.git#nightly
```

The update can be followed in this [PR](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/pull/114)

Comment: any devtools available for RN yet?

Answer (score 2):

Towards release

[See here](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/pull/114#issuecomment-699077480)

> Hi everyone! FYI we've published a "nightly build" branch for testing purposes. If you want to try out recoil with react native before we release next version, try install the nightly branch with the "install git branch" feature of npm/yarn:

> `npm install https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil.git#nightly`

> Or
> `yarn add https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil.git#nightly`

Answer (score 2):

Update:
RN support is now there in Recoil.js as Experimental.

https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/releases/tag/0.1.1

Answer (score -2):

Try using 'useRecoilValue' instead in your RecoilTest.js file

```
const [text, setText] = useRecoilValue(textState);
```

Comment: useRecoilValue provides only state value, not setText

Comment: This is wrong. `useRecoilValue` cannot be destructured and is a read-only value